# When I plug in earphones into my HTC Desire S, it dials the phone

Tags: htc-desire-s, headphone-jack

Every time I plug in my earphones into my HTC Desire S, it  starts calling the last dialed number automatically and starts the music after short interval.  Does anyone know about this problem?

Comment: It sounds like some hardware issue. Does your earphone have music controlls? Is the behavior the same with different earphones?

Comment: I plugged my earphone to some other HTC phone and this was not happening..Is it issue with the phone?

Comment: Does your earphone have music controlls? Is the behavior the same with different earphones?

Comment: Check out the default launch application when you plug a hardware like earphone to your device. Some phones has this option. Check out the music player setting which started the playing music when you connect the earphone and also check the setting of the calls.

Answer (score 3):

HTC Desire HD Android 2.3.5

I had exactly the same problem, would plug in standard headphones/ earphones/ aux cable to speakers... all of these would register on the phone as earphones with a mic built in for some reason.  it would cut music tracks short and play the next one or start ringing a call.

strangely, as i was searching for this thread, the problem has self corrected.  All that is different is that I updated ALL of my apps on google app store today.  This is the only factor that I have changed.  Try this!  I hope it works out for you as well as I know how frustrating it was!

best wishes

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on my Evo 3d.  I downloaded an app called [Headset Blocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idunnolol.headsetblocker) and it disabled the phone's headset remote abilities. This solved the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same issue with my HTC desire. My hypothesis is that my headphones or jack have a slight short and is activating the voice commands via the input channel. I am trying to see if there is a way to turn off voice commands on the headphone jack itself or all together without turning off the input channel so I can still use a headphone with a mic for phone calls.

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely a hardware problem. Go to the app store and download Headset Blocker if it  works on your current phone's version. It didn't work on mine so I had to use WizDroid. Open the app then activate it and it should fix the problem.